# Overriding create method in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm trying to write specs for a method that uses the #create method which writes to the database which is causing issues because its being created with an object that's not saved to the database -- does anyone know how to override #create so it doesn't try to save to the database when running specs?

I get this error:

```
     ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved:
   You cannot call create unless the parent is saved
```

Comment: create a mock object of the object that you are trying to save in the db so that you dont have to run create to get the object saved in the database

Answer (score 1):

As @Raghu pointed out, you need mocking/stubbing (see http://blog.firsthand.ca/2011/12/example-using-rspec-double-mock-and.html) to avoid actually running the create method.  You probably don't want to test if create actually works.  You are more likely testing that create is called on right time, on right model and with right options.

Answer (score 0):

This is the place to [use a Stub / Double](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs)  (formerly, and still commonly, known as "Mocks")